# mutate top_n values for each group

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to summarise top_n values in each group of `df` but I am having an error. I would like to keep other columns when I do this process, so `summarise` function is not preferable for me!

```
set.seed(123)
df<- data.frame(
  x   = runif(60),
  grp = gl(6, 10)
) 

#        x          grp
#    1  0.28757752   1
#    2  0.78830514   1
#    3  0.40897692   1
#    4  0.88301740   1
#    5  0.94046728   1
#    6  0.04555650   1
#    7  0.52810549   1
#    8  0.89241904   1
#    9  0.55143501   1
#    10 0.45661474   1
#    11 0.95683335   2

  df_top <- df%>%
      group_by(grp)%>%
      mutate(top_x=top_n(x,5))
```

> Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
>     no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

the point is I want to keep x column entirely after adding `top_x` column. How can I do that?

Comment: `top_n` is a table verb, not a helper function: `df %>%
      group_by(grp) %>%
      top_n(5, x)`

Comment: @alistaire ok. You remove five x values and like summarized the result.

Comment: There's nothing to `summarise` here, because there's no summary statistics to calculate (from your code, anyway).

Comment: @alistaire I just want to keep all x column after `top_n` or other function. Is that possible?

Comment: Oh, I think you're using the wrong function. Maybe `df %>%
      group_by(grp) %>%
      mutate(top_x = x %in% head(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE), 5))`, or if you really want to use `top_n`, `df %>%
      group_by(grp) %>%
      left_join(top_n(., 5, x) %>% mutate(top_x = TRUE))`

Comment: @alistaire works great! thanks.